# How to solve "IndexError: pop from empty list" Python 3

Tags: python, stack

I am trying to reverse a word using stack and `pop()`, I believe I am overlooking something.The idea is to have all the elements of the word in a new list, then pop them and have them in the original list. For a sample word to work with, you can use "rotate". Below is my attempt at solving it.

```py
def revbystack(x):
  stack = []
  for i in range(len(x)):
    stack.append(x[i])
    for i in range(len(x)):
      x[i] = stack.pop()

word = "rotate"
nw3 = list(word)

revbystack(nw3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is indentation. The nested for loop is executed for every iteration in outer for loop.

De-dent the nested for-loop:

```py
def revbystack(x):
    stack = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        stack.append(x[i])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = stack.pop()


word = "rotate"
nw3 = list(word)

revbystack(nw3)
print(nw3)  # ['e', 't', 'a', 't', 'o', 'r']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are nested within each other. Let's walk through what happens with your code.

First, you insert the first character of the word into the stack (i = 0). Then you perform the second loop for the length of x again; however, there is only one element in the stack. Therefore after the first iteration of the second loop the stack is empty.

Therefore you get an error saying you are popping from an empty stack.
In the future, try printing out the indices of your loops and the values you are trying to access to see what is going on :)